# How to pass a callback method between Xamarin Android activites

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, callback

I have created a Xamarin class library that will open the camera to capture a value and return it to the main activity(Xamarin Android). To return the value, I am planning to pass a callback method from the main application to the library activity with PutExtra and retrieve the value. However, I was unable to Serialize the method and pass it to the library. How can I do this? Or are there any other solutions to achieve this?

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much

Comment: @Cheesebaron You could post in answer.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT no, that doesn't make sense when it is a duplicate.